# Examples of usage of Effectual vs. Effective?

Tags: word-meaning

What is the difference between `effectual` and `effective`? I have seen the dictionary definition but there were no examples of usage of `effectual` that to me couldn't be substituted by `effective`. Or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Do you have any specific context where you have seen one or the other that you are asking about?

Comment: I have seen it on a project management presentation but the actual example escaped me... only the word cought my attention and made me curious.

Comment: The meanings are very similar if not identical, but as a rule of thumb I would say **do not use "effectual"**.  [*effectual* has been declining in popularity for about 150 years, while *effective* has been increasing in popularity.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=effectual%2Ceffective&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceffectual%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceffective%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **effectual** and **effective** have the **same meaning** - producing, or capable of producing, a desired or intended result. 
The only difference is preference and style - just choose the one that sounds the best in the sentence you are using. They are also **completely interchangeable**